# Are there any issues with posting screenshots of books/pages?

Tags: discussion, legal

I don't recall ever seeing this before so I am not sure if it is acceptable or not. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25389640/838807) which contains a couple of images which appear to be screenshots taken from an electronic book.

The OP also goes on to provide [this self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25414633/838807) which again contains a number of images (from what seems to be that same book).

The reason I ask is because I have heard a lot in the past in terms of making sure quotes/extracts are correctly referenced, and that they do not infringe on any copyrights etc.

Are there any specific actions we need to take if we include screenshots of books? e.g. provide link to original source or prove that it isn't breaching copyright in any way? (assuming it is OK to even post them in the first place)

Comment: Rule of thumb: Text should be text, not images. And of course, any citation should be properly attributed.

Comment: The OP seems to have [extensive](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26194180/3001761) [form](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26376509/3001761) [for](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26885679/3001761) [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25960215/3001761).

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Didn't change much (if any) over the next six months:http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a1198559

Comment: @Deduplicator oh for pity's... have you flagged it?

Answer (score 148):

Screenshots of pages from books **plainly should not ever be used**, even with citations. Images are not searchable and cannot be indexed, so a huge portion of the content just *isn't there* to screen readers.

These should be converted to plain text, using a blockquote with proper citation of where the content came from.

Comment: That certainly makes for a good reason not to use a screenshot, but is that really a reason to try to enforce it? I mean, how far is "can you type all that up instead" going to get us?

Comment: IMO - if the answer requires to much text to address the problem that the relevant excepts can't be manually typed out, then the question may be too broad

Comment: @psubsee2003: ahhh, I am already trying to work through my "too broad" issue on another meta question :/ But I am with you, I am not sure 3 pages of a book provides a useful/specific answer.

Comment: @musefan the question itself might not be too broad on its own (I can't really speak to that as I'm not familiar with the topic), but if specific excerpts can't be extracted  and all of those pages are necessary to completely answer the question, then it is too broad.

Comment: Citing so many pages to answer a SO question is  not going to fall under Fair Use, though, so even if the OP converted the image to text they would probably be infringing somebody's copyright. (Edit: ah, no, the book seems to be freely available.)

Comment: For some books, there are Google Books versions, and it can be helpful to link to the corresponding pages.  This is especially important in places where there's a question about whether something in the book is a typo, etc.  That's more important for questions than answers, though.  (Of course, citations are important, but images of the exact text are more important for questions.)

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I still can't imagine an *image* of the text being useful. You're still removing the searchability of the page. Just because there's a typo doesn't mean you need to take a screenshot of the text. Copy-pasting the excerpt or retyping, and then highlighting where the typo is at, would still be much more beneficial.

Comment: @animuson I absolutely agree with the part about searchability;  the text should definitely be transcribed.  My point was just that sometimes it may be useful to *additionally* have the original text.  It's easy to make transcription errors, and it's easy to "accidentally" "fix" "errors" in the original while transcribing.  There are a few questions where this has been important, in my experience.

Comment: @animuson E.g.,  [Little Schemer: length0 and mk-length](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19720833/1281433) is one that comes to mind.  The textbook creates solutions incrementally, so sometimes students think that earlier (incomplete) solutions are malfunctioning complete solutions.  Screenshots aren't necessary in this case, but consulting the original text was. It was useful to be able to link to the original text (via Google Books).

Comment: @Pekka: "*Citing so many pages to answer a SO question is not going to fall under Fair Use, though*" - do you have a source for that claim? I'm assuming, given the 'fair use' reference, that you're commenting as regards US law? One argument to the contrary: "Although “[n]either our court nor any of our sister circuits has ever ruled that the copying of an entire work *favors* fair use[,] . . . . courts have  concluded that such copying does not necessarily weigh against fair use." (citation: https://s3.amazonaws.com/s3.documentcloud.org/documents/693479/richard-prince-ruling.pdf)...

Comment: ...that's page 19, line 19; it directly discusses images, not books, but I can't see that the same wouldn't be true of books. Though, admittedly, I can't see any reason that an answer to a question should *need* to feature three scanned pages, rather than a carefully summarised, typed-up excerpt.

Comment: Personally, whenever I include a screenshot showing text, I take care to use the alt text to transcribe it, eg: `![Screenshot: "Text text and more text blah blah lorem ipsum stuff..."](http://example.com/screenshot.png)` - is this reasonable?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol If it's a chart or something that requires an image for organization or to demonstrate a specific format, that's the best thing you can do. If it's just text and the layout isn't important, I think blockquotes are better.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Well, you're solving the problem for screen readers and spiders, but it's still problematic for, say, someone who is visually impaired and has the font-size on their computer set to a much larger size so they can read it. Plain text can easily be increased in size, whereas an image can only be zoomed with lossy, blurry effects. It really depends on what it is though.

Comment: @animuson the overwhelming consensus is that this isn't OK, but do you have suggestions for action? Write out the images and look for a citation ourselves? Flag the Qs/As? Comment (the specific OP seems unwilling to reconsider, but this might work in general)?

Comment: Your answer makes some sense. However, when I see words like, "not ever," my B.S. meter starts flashing.  How about self published authors? Many (most?) publishers would be thrilled to have excerpts from their books copied and cited. (Especially if a link to purchase the book is provided.) If the page has an image.... "An image is worth a thousand words," right?  Good point about adding text to make the image searchable.

Comment: @l3x It's simply not a matter of whether someone would like it or not. It has nothing to do with whether or not it might violate copyright. We simply do not allow *images of text*. No matter the context, they are not allowed.

Comment: @animuson Why not? Is this a new policy?

Comment: @l3x It's always been policy. It's just not everyone cares enough to convert an image to text when they come across it. I certainly don't. Doesn't mean people should do it, and we definitely shouldn't encourage it.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to cite the source when quoting it like this (in a question or answer), yes.

If the author didn't cite it, either edit in a citation if you know what the source is, or comment/flag indicating that a citation is needed.

Comment: OK that's fine. Do we have anything I could link to in the comment to back up my suggestion? Like something that explains why it's important to do so. I feel my comment alone might not provide enough motivation for the user

Comment: @musefan Plagiarizing content is a problem in general, not just because it's an SE rule.  That said, if you see plagiarized content you can flag for a mod to resolve the issue.

Comment: I don't agree at all. Citing someone else's text is one thing – reproducing a whole page inside a SO post is something completely different. Seriously, this is like playing arbritrary parts, including "everything but the opener and credits" of someone else's movie in your cinema, but saying that this form of content reproduction is OK because "you did cite the director". It's not.

Comment: @MarcusMüller You think quoting *one page* of a book is equivalent to reproducing everything but the credits of a movie?  That would mean that the book would need to be a one page long book.  Typically we don't call those "books" if they're only a page long; that'd be a pamphlet.

Comment: @Servy: not the point; if you're not even processing the page's content, that wouldn't be a citation in the correct meaning of that word. It would be a reproduction, of a significant part of the book. Imagine this: you're someone who offers private courses on higher math. Instead of coming up with your own questions, you just copy the pages with exercises from someone else's textbook. You give credit. That is **not** citing. That's just reproducing without paying royalties. I'm all for open access; but that's really not much short of stealing from the author.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, a quote from a book is not a citation from that book. The citation that would follow it is the citation from that book.  Your assertion that no work can ever be quoted, ever, in any context, is simply not valid.  It's entirely acceptable to include a short quote from a book when *asking a question about that content* and to include that short quotation as a part of another original work.  Such usage will fall under fair use, and would not be "stealing"; it is an entirely appropriate situation in which to quote another's work.

Comment: @Servy you seem to have misunderstood me: *no work can ever be quoted, ever* is definitely not what I said. Reproduction of a whole page is not quoting, ever.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, it is a quote.  You appear to not be familiar with the definition of a quote.  As far as misunderstanding you, you've equated including a quote of a book with stealing that book, and have equated referencing a small portion of a work in order to ask a specific question about that portion with reproducing the entirety of a work exclusively for commercial gain

Comment: as said, you misunderstand. I don't say including *any* part of a book in a work of yours is stealing :) But reproducing a complete page isn't *just* a quote. A quote, by definition, is *the reproduction someone else's statement or thoughts*, **not** *the reproduction of a comprehensive part of someone else's work*. I can quote Cesar in a book, I can quote whole concepts of Shakespeare's dramas, but as soon as I start using pages of Tolstoi, I'm leaving the *quoting* business and enter the *copy shop owner* business.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, reproducing a page is in fact a quote.  A quote is, by definition, "to speak or write (a passage) from another usually with credit acknowledgment" (Mirriam Webster)  Nothing about the definition of a quote defines the amount of content quoted.  Also, a single page of a book is not "a comprehensive part of someone else's work".  It's quoting a *very small* portion of the work, and in this context would meet virtually every pillar of fair use, making such a quote rather conclusively not plagiarism, in this context.

Comment: Wait, you're mixing in the aspect of plagiarism here, which I've not even remotely touched (and don't want to bring into this discussion). However, copying a whole page is not "a very small portion" of someone else's work; I really can't see a case where you'd do that in a book without incurring your lectoriat's wrath, and I'd say the same applies online. If that page can stand alone, you're copying a comprehensive piece of work, and if it can't, you should be re-phrasing / re-formulating this, anyway, instead of pixelwise reproducing it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller The fundamental question being asked here is whether or not including the quote is plagiarism.  Your assertion that the quote isn't even a quote is conclusively proven false by merely looking at the definition of the term, by which this would unambiguously apply.  So what, are you just saying that you don't like it?  You assert that he shouldn't be doing this, but you've provided no basis for that assertion.  Why shouldn't he quote a section of a book he wants to ask a question about?  If you're not concerned about plagiarism or IP rights, then what is  your concern?

Comment: *The fundamental question being asked here is whether or not including the quote is plagiarism* I wasn't discussing that.

Comment: I do understand our misunderstanding, now .. and it's my fault

Comment: @MarcusMüller So then what are you discussing?  You haven't used the word "plagiarism" but you seem to be arguing that this is an inappropriate reproduction of the work, which is what plagiarism is.

Comment: so, point is that your answer is about avoiding plagiarism, which, in my understanding is *using someone else's work in a manner that suggests it's your own*. And that, without doubt, can be avoided by correctly citing the original author. My point, and I see how I've been discussing off-topic, is, that this "acting like it was your work" isn't the whole problem – it's also the fact that you're just reproducing someone else's work in a manner that is making your post a reproduction of someone else's work without the original author's authorization

Comment: @MarcusMüller So you're asserting that it's a copyright violation?  Again, this usage would fall squarely under fair use, so no, it would not be a copyright violation.  I have said this several times.  This would be an entirely legal and appropriate quotation of the work, under that clause.  Every single pillar of the concept applies to this case.