# Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, images, warning-message

Can we add some guidance to discourage new users from posting screenshots of their code and/or errors?

It may not be the most common problem, but I've run into it more than a few times. New-ish user asks a question and rather than taking the time to copy and paste their code or console errors into the post they try to just take a screenshot of their editor and dump it into the question...

Doing so breaks a lot of the search-ability of the post and renders a lot of the content useless to users using screen readers.

---

Perhaps a simple tooltip could be displayed to users when they try to post their first few images. Something along the lines of:

> Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **Don't post images of code or error messages.** Instead copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly.

---

Related:
[Are there any issues with posting screenshots of books/pages?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284577/are-there-any-issues-with-posting-screenshots-of-books-pages)
[Why may I not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: *"But I cannot paste the code directly, because then the system tells me there is too much code in my question"* replied the poor user.

Comment: _"Ah, but you should have isolated the issue and created a MCVE."_ replied the more experienced user. @FrédéricHamidi

Comment: So put *that* in your message in the first place :) It could be an X-Y problem, so repeating the MCVE mantra just in case may be worth it.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I see where you're coming from, but do we really need to add an explicit "don't do this, even when trying to circumvent other filters"? Seems like a simple "don't" should suffice.

Comment: I was only trying to address the case of users bumping into your suggested limitation while trying to overcome another one. Not every user does that, but there are some who do. Ironically, not every user reads the popup messages we throw in their faces when they ask questions from newish accounts. But there are some who do :)

Comment: [my "favorite" "screen shot"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QYCqB.jpg). It is real, posted as is in the question ([10K link at Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/294842/basic-on-the-ti84))

Comment: You are not asking for the right feature.  SE continues to struggle at coming up with a good filter for the front page.  This is an ideal one.  Big screen-shot = -100 points.

Comment: But, what about [visual programming languages like LabVIEW](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303624/reputation-points-for-images-is-a-problem-for-visual-languages)?  Or are those just better supported elsewhere?  Yes it's a corner case (see the 500 or so [tag:labview] questions)

Comment: You know the biggest problem with posting error messages as text? You lose the colouring that makes them easier to read. (I carefully went out of my way on [the Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) to make sure that the colouring remained, it’s worth while in such environments.) For the most part, adding a new syntax highlighting thing for error messages wouldn’t be impossible, but you’re not going to get normal people including the language identifiers, nor do I expect good detection semantics being applied.

Comment: I mentioned it in [How do I create a screenshot to illustrate a post?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99734/155831) but that is a long post and it kind of gets buried there.  I'd like to see it promoted to a pop-up tip for newbies..

Comment: Also releated: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: What's even worse: screenshots with sample data for questions related to SQL and databases  (e.g. a screenshot with the results of a query in the SQL client)

Comment: My favourite: "screen shot" of code, taken with a phone camera pointing at the physical screen, Moiré pattern and all... "because it's quicker to post that way". Can't seem to find that gem anymore, but it's there somewhere.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Something weird going on with the security of that link; Firefox refuses to go there.

Comment: Another bad situation is when a question claims that a given Markdown parser is not rendering properly and instead of posted the HTML code output by the parser, they post a screenshot of how their browser is displaying the HTML. Completely unhelpful.

Comment: @JanDoggen: that’s odd. Try again? Never had any trouble before.

Comment: @Chris The messages are that the connection gets reset, https://play.rust-lang.org/ has no identity information, it is not an encrypted link. If I go to https://www.rust-lang.org/ it works, so it could be something like a certificate not supporting subdomains.

Comment: Or maybe SO should implement some [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) system to help the user copy and paste code!

Comment: @oliverpool It would avoid copy-pasting code wrong and introducing new errors or accidental fixes :p

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: _"You lose the colouring that makes them easier to read"_ -- I know some may find this hard to believe, but there was a time when we answered programming questions (and lots of other kinds too) **without any syntax or keyword highlighting, and indeed without any formatting at all**. In any case, whatever modest benefit might be had from differently-colored text, is completely overwhelmed by the benefits to searchability and accessibility (again, some might be surprised to find that not everyone perceives color the same way they do) that are so much more important.

Comment: You could post a screenshot of answer code(!)

Comment: @apaul34208 the more realistic scenario is that the experienced would just downvote and move on.

Comment: Considering adding images to posts is not granted until their rep is at 10, what is the level of rep that you see this with?  You are saying new users but are you talking 50-100 rep, 1 rep, or what?

Comment: @bluefeet I was more thinking rep of a independent, when the user posts their first few images. Say when they post their first 1-3

Comment: @apaul34208 I can see that yes this might be an issue, but how do you distinguish when a user has posted a screenshot and may have included code? Generating a warning or a tooltip when they have already included everything seems to maybe be noisy to users.

Comment: @bluefeet If I remember correctly we already show a few messages to users when they use a feature for the first time or first couple of times. That and I doubt showing a brief tooltip to users a few times would be a deal breaker for them, small price to pay for getting a question answered.

Comment: @bluefeet I'm not suggesting that we try to automatically decipher whether an image contains code, just trying to discourage the practice and give other users a leg to stand on when we tell people not to do it.

Comment: @apaul34208 I'm going to `status-review` this for now.  I've got to think about how we can implement it and not be noisy, no guarantees but we're looking at it.

Comment: What about a code-insertion wizard. It pops up a JS dialog (like the insert hyperlink CTRL-L) and you paste code into a text box. It can warn you if it's too long, directing you to the MCVE advice. The code would be successfully inserted into the question (or answer) with proper indentation, etc.

Comment: @PeterDuniho: oh, I know, and quite agree with you. It’s still sad that you lose the colouring by having it as text.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan: _"It’s still sad that you lose the colouring"_ -- I think no one's saying you can't post _both_ (certainly I'm not). If a person feels the coloring adds enough to be worth including, that's fine. The problem is when the information is not also included as searchable, accessible text.

Comment: I'd agree about code, however there may be cases where an image/screenshot of an error is reasonable.  For instance, if the error only presents when running on an external device, the only practical way to share it may be to take a screenshot/photo of the external device.  Not everything writes debugging messages to a conveniently accessible developer's console.

Comment: @gnat What's funny is that that's a completely valid "screenshot".  TI-Basic requires commands be selected from a menu, and re-typing the code would disguise a common beginner mistake - that they had used the letter keys instead of the commands

Comment: the proposal is to discourage, not to ban screenshots... also you can always take a screenshot of your code and images.google it to find answers.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that some users are on networks that block SO's image server. So it's definitely important to understand images as supplementary - some users won't be able to see them at all.

Comment: @Izkata if only it wouldn't be turned so that it's impossible to read

Comment: @gnat your question link now 404's. I assume it was deleted. RIP precious content which is now MIA....

Comment: @bluefeet How did the review go?

Comment: @apaul34208 it's a 6-8 somethingish process. Have patience young one! :)

Comment: @bluefeet I figured that would be the case just thought I should check in. While I have you, would you mind taking a look at [another feature request](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271829/add-indication-that-canned-comments-are-from-review), it never received a status tag.

Comment: @apaul34208 [A status tag is never guaranteed](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263662/can-we-have-a-guaranteed-pipeline-for-responses-from-stack-exchange)

Answer (score 87, accepted):

This has been implemented network-wide.  When a user has <= 15 rep, they will see a message in the image uploader that says:

> Images are useful in a post, but **make sure the post is still clear without them**. If you post images of code or error messages, copy and paste or type the actual code or message into the post directly.

If you have less than the [new user privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) (< 10 on SO) and you attempt to post an image, we will now include a link to the image and a little message to the user:

> [image]

Previously these users would get an error message when they attempted to post.

**Note:** the link conversion will happen only on sites where image embedding is blocked for new users, i.e. on SO.

Basically, we aren't preventing users from including screenshots; we are just trying to discourage low rep users from including screenshots by themselves.

Comment: Is the two link maximum still enforced now that images are automatically linked?

Comment: Nice. Is the image converted to embedded automatically when an edit is made to the post by someone over 15 rep, or do we have to manually fix the markdown?

Comment: You'll have to manually fix it, @theB. This involves typing an exclamation point. This is something you should only do if the image actually warrants embedding, which is why it's a manual step - there will be cases where that is inappropriate.

Comment: @MichaelMyers Yes, on SO you will still need at least 10 rep to post more than 2 links

Comment: @Shog9 - Thanks for the clarification. Its now added to my list of things to double check when making edits. Hopefully this also means that there will be less links to questionable image hosts that need manual merging over to the stack imgur.

Comment: Yes, that is the goal, @theB!

Comment: And then people would [post links to their pictures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36005134/11683) instead of the actual pictures. :(

Comment: @GSerg Yes, that does happen but you can always edit the post to embed the images.

Comment: @bluefeet These are screenshots of code. I don't want to embed them. They should have been code in the first place. apaul34208 [asked](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/11683) how we stop people from posting code as images and you said there's already a limitation in place. And now there are people who work around the limitation by posting links to screenshots of their code, which is even worse than posting screenshots of code :(

Comment: @GSerg Actually prior to this, users were blocked from posting images altogether which was even more frustrating because they would include comments like "I can't post images".  We cannot force users to post code, the most we can do is educate them on how to properly use the site. You as a high rep user with edit privileges can easily edit the post to include the screenshot as I did with the initial question you included.

Comment: really, I don't this has the necessary effect. People are still adding links to screeshots of terminal output, and code, in hundreds. A clear **You must not add screenshots of code or textual error messages instead of using the text itself.** would be the right thing here – also imposing a *rule* that allows people "justify" a downvote (or even a close vote!) on screenshot-only questions

Comment: One year later, this has clearly not solved the problem. Pictures of code rather seems to get more and more popular.

Comment: Not allowing new users to post images will still not discourage them from posting screenshots of code. I've seen several cases where new users post links to screenshots of code. I think that along with the "you're not allowed to embed images" message they should also get the "make sure the post is clear without them" message. Or simply put it back as it was first and not allow them to post images and don't include a link for them. The best thing would be to detect if the image contains code or not and if it does block the image, but I understand if that's too difficult to implement.

Comment: Also, maybe add a close reason "this post contains screenshots of code" might be useful.

Comment: @DonaldDuck From my experience, simply blocking all image links of new users might even be better, perhaps encouraging them to work on their prose as well as their code. Maybe with a timelimit? Your post must make sense (or survive) for the first 24 hours in which the images are held back. Detecting the filetype of links would add to server load, though, and would have to be sandboxed for security.

Comment: Hilarious that you post an image of text without giving the text as text.

Comment: I dint think adding a link to image is helpfull tell the user why they cant post an image of code and reminding them of [MVP]

Comment: 6 years later and we're still inundated with links to screenshots of code. Can we not simply apply the same logic that blocks embedding images to also block links to `*.imgur.com`?

Comment: Why is there no guidance in the Help Center (specifically https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about screenshots?  It would be nice to be able to reply to questions with only screenshots of code and to refer to them to published guidance instead of resorting to a "because I said so" argument.

Comment: Also, what is the point of showing the warning only for new users of <= 15 reputation?  Why not do it for *all* users?  I would not expect it to have much negative impact on high-reputation users since I expect that they rarely post screenshots anyway.

Answer (score 156):

If you are asking a question about an error or code, it **needs** to be in there as text otherwise it won't be searchable for other users.

I think screenshots of errors and code can be useful but only as supplementary information to the actual code/error as text. I find it helpful to see the actual error window sometimes as it helps me remember where I've seen this before or where exactly the error is coming from.

> Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please
>   make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. **If you post
>   images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the
>   actual code/message into the post directly.**

In rewording like this it also frames the issue positively (do this) rather than negatively (don't do this).

Comment: Do we really want a duplicate of code + picture saying the same thing? At that point I would edit out the picture. I can see a warning message that code should be in text, but after that its probably easier to replace images with text via editing ourselves and politely reminding people.

Comment: @DoubleDouble can't it just be added as alt text? If I'm remembering correctly, Stack supports that and I tend to do that whenever I can.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy I suppose it can, but whats the point of a redundant picture when only text is required

Comment: @SeldomNeedy I *never* want to see a screenshot of code or textual errors (unless it is to illustrate a problem with the IDE).  I can't copy/paste code from an alt attribute without jumping through extra hoops.

Comment: @cimmanon I'd say there are a limited number of cases in which this actually makes sense to do. Having a helpful tooltip that says when this is appropriate versus not is something we can probably all agree on.

Comment: @DoubleDouble cimmanon gives a decent example; we have some grey cases where someone is using some kind of visual interface *for programming* (meaning it's a programming question, not a usage-question for [Superuser](http://superuser.com)) and then it makes sense to want a screen. I would say this should of course be the exception and not the rule, meaning I largely agree with you; askers should not be allowed to screencap just because they are too lazy to re-type a 100-character error-message assuming they cannot just paste it.

Comment: Good luck trying to "copy and paste or type" LabVIEW code.

Comment: @SeldomNeedy And, keep in mind that usage of software designed to aid programming is on topic here. (It's on topic at SU, too, but less likely to get helpful replies.)

Comment: @Seldom 'Where's Monica' Needy: A case where I always want a screenshot is the output of console.log etc., because the colors and what is inside an expandable section and what isn't is essential to identify subtle misunderstandings such as the poster misinterpreting the variable type (e.g. JSON versus an actual object).

Answer (score 20):

Such a message should link to instructions for capturing error messages, since there isn't always an obvious mechanism.

Something along the lines of

- [7 Ways to Copy Text or Error Messages from Windows](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-copy-text-or-error-messages-from-any-dialog-boxes-in-windows/)

except that we should probably have our own version hosted here on Stack Overflow Meta / Stack Overflow Help, and it should cover more operating systems.

Comment: `CTRL+C` has been available since Win95 at least - I'm not sure why a quarter century later it is still like secret knowledge.

Answer (score -9):

I agree that most screenshots of code are pure lazyness. And especially because putting stuff in working code will force you to think about what you've done, it is good to enforce a rule like: 'avoid posting screenshots of code'.

But, I can think of a good reason to add screenshots and sometimes even omit the code itself. IDE's like Android Studio can display lots of debug info right next to the code, which will often show that the problem you have is not because of bad input values. Then, the code itself *may* just be disturbing extra and the screenshot *may* be much more useful. Moreover, in a screenshot you can grab multiple parts of multiple windows, which can give a good overview.

I'd say it all depends on whether the poster has thought about how to best present the issue, and decided knowingly to (also) post the screenshot(s).

Answer (score -34):

## I agree with this, but...

Don't ask the whole text of the error message.

Sometimes, it's not possible to obtain the text of a console error or multiple errors. This is a big problem when debugging in IE11 or when you have a specific CSS behaviour that should(n't) happen (this point is arguable).

Sometimes, the user simply doesn't know how to copy those. Or the error is simply a broken image or something.

There are many situations. Each computer and situation is different. Asking for the text representation of a very peculiar error when you can't (Example: a message box) is off-putting.

In the situations that it is possible to re-type the whole message, please do so. If not, at least include the title/error number with part of the description and use the image as a suplementar media.

---

In conclusion, only ask for the code in textual form. It's silly to even have the code in a printscreen.

Comment: If you have a long message box error, you should still type out the title or something relevant from it so that it's searchable. And then post it with the screenshot.

Comment: If you can't copy-paste the error (this is assuming only the cases where you actually get an error message- In cases where, say, your css moved the image the wrong way... Well, there's no error there to even consider. It's just not behaving as intended) then it should _still_ be typed into the question. You can't Google an error and get the image based on the text in the image- At least, not yet. The error needs to be typed out, be it manually or by copy-paste, _somewhere_ in the question.

Comment: @Kendra I disagree. But if it is to write something, what about writting only a portion of the error? An error message, sometimes, could be as large as 200 characters. That is, depending on the error.

Comment: I realized I missed that situation in my comment, but slicedtoad had already covered long messages so I saw no point in editing to cover that. Typing the important part of the message, for instance the first line, is fine for longer messages, along with a screenshot so we get the whole error. For shorter messages where only "copy and paste" is the issue, you might as well type out the whole comment.

Comment: _" it's not possible to obtain the text of a console error or multiple errors"_ -- if the person asking the question can view the text, they can type it in. Yes, copy/paste is most convenient. But it's _always_ possible to include the exact text of an error message that is relevant to the question. As for "multiple errors", frankly it's a good thing for users to be inhibited in that scenario, lest they drop a huge mass of errors, most of which have nothing to do with the underlying problem, into their post. If all those error messages are important, the person can damn well type them all in.

Comment: @slicedtoad At first, I didn't noticed properly your comment. I've edited the answer to reflect that.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I had a problem with a VB program that only failed on certain computers. The error messages couldn't be acquired in any other way besides a printscreen (because, on Windows, you can't copy the text from message boxes). I haven't posted it on StackOverflow. But re-typing 500 characters is so off-putting that makes people give up from posting. Do you really think anyone would write all the errors? I wouldn't.

Comment: @Kendra I didn't noticed his comment at first. I hope it is better now.

Comment: _"But re-typing 500 characters is so off-putting that makes people give up from posting. Do you really think anyone would write all the errors?"_ Just to be that person- I would. =) (Granted, I really like typing... A lot... So I may be the exception.) To answer your comment to me, your answer does indeed look better.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel you at least must have typed the relevant part of the error message to google it...

Comment: @1010 "[...] at least include the title/error number with part of the description and use the image as a suplementar media."

Comment: _"But re-typing 500 characters is so off-putting that makes people give up from posting"_ -- I doubt that there is actually an error message that contains 500 characters that are **all** actually important to the comprehension of the question. But if such an error does exist, then yes: if someone wants an answer to their question, they damn well better be prepared to type in all 500 characters. The biggest liability SO has is all the lazy people posting questions that they can't be bothered to present in a useful way. The more we discourage those people, the better.

Comment: @PeterDuniho It's not for the lazy, but for those who can't post it in a textual way. Lazy people? Yes, make them sweat! Impossibility to obtain the message in a textual way? No, lets help those!

Comment: _"for those who can't post it in a textual way"_ -- you are talking about a mythical, non-existent person. Communication on the Internet is inherently textual. There is not a single person using the Internet for communication that is literally incapable of posting information as text. There are only people who are too lazy to input the text that is required for best, most efficient use of the technology.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Lets not go to "best, most efficient use"... Because there's nothing efficient about re-writting an error message and re-checking it ever 2-5 words

Comment: Are you talking about an error message with 500 random characters? In that case why not just say, "error message box with random characters/gibberish"? It is unlikely the message means anything useful outside of error codes, obvious identifiers, or the first 10 characters. However, if the exact gibberish is relevant, I would agree that an image as supplemental information would be a good thing.

Comment: _"Because there's nothing efficient about re-writing an error message"_ -- let's **do** go there, because the question of efficiency has to include the whole picture. The entire point of Stack Overflow is that people can search its contents to find the answers to questions that have been asked previously. This is negated when the information is not textual. "Efficient" does not mean "least effort in the short run".

Comment: @PeterDuniho Basically, if I have a message saying "Unhandled exception blah on blah on blah on blah on blah on blah ... ", I have to write that whole stuff? The example I'm going to give is a bad one because it has the textual representation of the error: http://i.imgur.com/Zhp5fUd.png But now imagine the same error **without** the text box. How screwed would I have to be?

Comment: _"How screwed would I have to be"_ -- honestly, if you can't be bothered to take the minute or so it would take to transcribe the error message shown there, why should you expect anyone else to take the time to compose a useful answer to the question? It's not like anyone's insisting you transcribe _War and Peace_ or anything like that. Quit whining, and get on board with posting **useful** questions. Questions that include critical information as images instead of text are simply not useful. Period. I don't care how hard it seems to you to type it in; **you still type it in**.

Comment: @PeterDuniho `Quit whining, and get on board with posting useful questions` <-- This is not a question... And I'm not the one whining. I'm just exposing a problem that (I don't have but) may happen to some other users.

Comment: _"I'm just exposing a problem that (I don't have but) may happen to some other users"_ -- Your comments are all written in the first person, so forgive me for thinking it was you with the problem. That said, no one has the problem. It's a **non-problem**. You have imagined the problem. Typing the question is what questioners are expected to do, and they are expected to type all of the important details. If they cannot copy/paste the text but also cannot be bothered to type the text by hand, they don't deserve an answer to their question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I give up...

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: Why are we arguing about how much text is too much to retype.  **You should never retype, that introduces transcription errors**  Instead, learn [how to capture the error message in text form](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-copy-text-or-error-messages-from-any-dialog-boxes-in-windows/)

Comment: @PeterDuniho "*Questions that include critical information as images instead of text are simply not useful. Period*" I disagree with having such absolute thinking. Many times a visual interface error (*not textual*) can be somewhat explained in a single sentence, but the details are best captured by an image, aiding in clarity to the point where I would consider it "critical". But I do think both should be there, the simple textual description and the picture.

Comment: @BenVoigt I was unaware about the first method. I surelly will try it next time!

Comment: @DoubleDouble: _"I disagree with having such absolute thinking"_ -- it doesn't really seem so, as you in the same comment wrote _"I do think both should be there"_. I'm not saying images of errors can't be useful, just that they can't be used _instead_ of the actual text. Please note also that this entire Q&A is about "code and error messages". Comments must be brief, so I take as given that readers can keep the context in mind, so that I don't have to keep restating that we are talking about code and error messages.

Comment: @DoubleDouble: _"context, which you seemed to change"_ -- then you simply inferred erroneously. Every conclusion of yours that follows from that error is also in error.

Comment: If I get a NullPointer error, I will call it such and then provide a more detailed stack trace. If, for some reason, I was completely unable to capture the text and it was "too much" (entire page) to type, I would link to an image of it and not bog down my post with so much detail. If you prefer that the entire error be in text, you are welcome to edit it.

Comment: @DoubleDouble `If you prefer that the entire error be in text, you are welcome to edit it` might as well be saying "If someone needs to rewrite the error I was too lazy to type so that they can answer MY question, then that's on them." It's a fact that [Code/errors posted as images are next to useless](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5212501). It's also a fact that you don't know what's relevant in the error, or else you'd have fixed it. If you aren't willing to guarantee you've included all the relevant information in your question, then don't expect people to be willing to answer it.

Comment: Online OCR for any text.

Answer (score -63):

If posting a screenshot is easier for the user than posting the code, then maybe the system should gently bend itself towards that?

Posting code on SO is actually quite hard and I’ve struggled with it myself. When you paste a bunch of code, it starts off as being formatted as text, and you must do lots of work to restore the indentation and the like.

Maybe this is a source of pride for some people who can do that, but in some cases I’ve honestly found myself thinking that instead of messing around in the Markdown editor, I’d like to drop a screenshot in from where the code gets OCRed out with already the correct formatting.

Maybe it’s required qualification for using the site that you can correctly format and post code. Or is it another of those things that discourages new people? I don’t know, I haven’t studied usage as much. But certainly the code-posting experience itself could also use improvement. Maybe also something like, if you paste in something that looks like code, then apply correct formatting to it, don’t require me to do gruntwork to fix it.

Comment: You consider pressing one button "lots of work" to format the code as code?

Comment: Select your code and then press the code (`{}`) button to indent it. It will add 4 spaces infront of each line. The "other" indentation (like code in a method) is kept as it is, but you're IDE should format that anyway.

Comment: _"Posting code on SO is actually quite hard"_ -- if there are things that SO can do that makes it easier for users to post questions _that are well-formatted and easily understood_, then by all means those types of features should be requested. But the issue here is that screenshots in lieu of actual text _detract_ from the usefulness of the question. It might be hard to post a good question, but it's a _lot_ harder to answer a bad question.

Comment: If formatting in the question post itself is difficult for you, pre-format the code in a text editor / programming editor and make sure the least indented lines are 4 spaces (or I think equivalently one tab?) indented.  You can do this in Notepad++ and many others by selecting the code and using TAB/Shift-TAB to correctly indent.  Then copy/paste into the appropriate part of the answer.

Comment: Honest question: what is so hard about it? The way you describe it I am imagining the black and white "struggling consumer" from a bad infomercial! There is no Markdown formatting to it. It's just regular code with an extra 4 leading spaces. Honestly I didn't know about the auto-format button because it's so easy to do in Vim. Maybe something to do with the runnable snippet thing that I never use?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I don't think *"hard"* is the best word to describe the problem. I would use *"unintuitive"* and *"continuously annoying"*.  The fact that the interface is not intuitive is easily seen by looking at the number of edits that are necessary to "fix code formatting". In the C tag, posts by newbies frequently require a formatting edit by a more experienced user. Why is that? There's something obviously wrong with a system where a newbie can't successfully post some code without assistance from a more experienced user.

Comment: @user3386109 Why? Because the newbies can't follow directions. Seriously. Four leading spaces is not that hard. I make a lot of these edits and it's all the same kinds of problems: actually but 8 or 16 or 20 leading spaces, didn't quite put 4 leading spaces, tried to use `inline formatting` to format a block, etc. What do you propose to do about that? There's already a button, a tooltip, and a big expandable example that explains how to do it, but [these people](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/borderlands/images/6/63/Shark_computer.gif/revision/latest?cb=20121014111138) still don't get it.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist LOL, blame the user...

Comment: @user3386109 As opposed to blame the platform? It's not like StackOverflow isn't bending over backwards here to make it obvious what you're supposed to do, and yet every day we are bombarded by nonsense from people who **obviously haven't read** all the warnings, help, etc. I ask again: **what do you propose to do about it?** We can snark back and forth all day about whose fault it is, but you're suggesting it's on StackOverflow to "do something" -- what, then? What is your fix?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist To experience a different UI, go post code on Apple's developers forum. On Apple's forum, the indentation is easy to get right. But the newbies always end up with code that's ________. Fill in the blank, and we'll talk.

Comment: @user3386109 So make a feature request that StackOverflow do it the way Apple does it, whatever that is? I don't even have an account there so I think "Go make an account and spend enough time there that you understand the pros and cons of their system" is very fair or even relevant. Honestly I did poke around their forums a little bit but I don't see any way to get an idea what their UI is like, and tbh the few code samples I did find had formatting problems, just like ours do.

Comment: @user3386109>  if Apple's platform is so great, I see no objection to letting all the guys who are too lazy to spend 2 minutes to type their own problem so people give them free help go over there. Seriously, how can you expect someone who can't even get basic text formatting right to write code?

Comment: @user3386109 While we should always be looking for ways to make things better, SO's mark up is hardly that difficult just for simple code formatting. It is simply not that difficult to spend 10 minutes looking at the formatting options and figuring it out; you just mouse over the buttons and maybe try them to see what it does. At some point, the user really is just being lazy, and that's not fair to people offering free help.

Comment: To be fair I don't think we can expect people whose question amounts to "Code not working, plz fix' and dumping their entire code base into a question can be expected to spend any extra time how to format their post.

Comment: Did everyone here forget that **not everyone can read images** and **images tend to rot away**? And even if an OCR program could fix the issue, and we had a lot of servers dedicated to handling it, how do you handle the case of someone taking a full-page screenshot?