# Code on screenshots audit

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/9800696). I voted to close it as

> Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers

(Bold mine). For me, a screenshot of the code is not quite useful, and formally does not match the requirement of "in the question itself". [This meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) also does not approve code screenshots.

So, can/should this be removed from audits?

Comment: Note that post tagged "php" and "android"... Unless you have good understanding of quality of questions in these tags I'd strongly recommend "skip" as an action (possibly with downvote).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov So you are saying *not* having the neccessary info *in the question itself*, only (maybe) in some pictures, should be ok in some tags? Or just that some tags are bexond saving anyway?

Comment: @Deduplicator I treat "android" tag as more-or less separate site. The linked question is actually one of better samples you can find there (and strictly speaking has information in the post, just not in a form recommended on SO). Posts that asked/answered/voted in that tag are very likely be opposite to what I'd think should be done - so skipping is practical solution for me. Note that I do not mean "beyond saving" - just I have other tags to spend my votes on with more satisfaction for me.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Yes, it should removed from the audits because you are completely correct.

I just wonder what bozos upvote such crap.

Downvote, close-vote, and if you can, delete-vote.

Comment: BUT LOOK AT ALL THE PRETTY COLORS

Comment: Shouldn't the question be tagged as low-quality? So either the OP or someone else can edit the question?

Comment: @Rolfツ: That's what downvoting and closing mean. Though I really doubt that one will ever be improved sufficiently. So in the end, it should be deleted.