# Images being interpreted as incorrectly formatted code

Tags: support, bug, quality-filter, not-properly-formatted-as-code

Stack Exchange is interpreting some of my images as "un-indented/un-formatted code".
It won't let me post.
This is the part that is being flagged:

```
[![SecondImage][2]][2]  
[![ThirdImage][3]][3]  
[![FourthImage][4]][4]
```

Comment: We need your complete post to understand what might be wrong. Can you post a gist or a screenshot here?

Comment: If you're talking about [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34597158/1947286) see: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @apaul34208 That's interesting. How does it know the difference?

Comment: Not sure, just a heads up.

Comment: Screenshot of code != code. For one, you can't scroll with a screenshot of a scrollbar.

Comment: it should still be allowed.

Answer (score 13):

I assume you're seeing the big red error:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut.

as shown in this image:

[image: error not properly formatted code]

You get this error because your image markup is not separated by at least a blank line.

To overcome this I suggest to change your markup to this (just blank lines will do as well)

```
### User 1
[![SecondImage][2]][2]  
### User 2
[![ThirdImage][3]][3]  
### User 3
[![FourthImage][4]][4]
```

Which results in this:

#### User 1

[image: SecondImage]

#### User 2

[image: ThirdImage]

#### User 3

[image: FourthImage]

If you really don't want to have those empty lines there or provide text or a heading for your pictures you can fallback to using plain/raw html tags:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wNQa.jpg?s=64&g=1"><br />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/JUOzO.png?s=32&g=1"><br />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/qj33e.png?s=48&g=1"><br />
```

which gets rendered as:

[image]
[image]
[image]

You could even leave out the `<br />` at the end to have images next to each other, something that isn't possible with only markdown.

Comment: It is possible to have the images next to each other by using Markdown. Unless you are getting a big red error as discussed above. But Superuser site is not bugged down by this problem at all and I have created a number of how-to's using medium sized images on a line as a way of creating a thumbnail gallery. It's odd that it's not working on Stackoverflow...

Comment: Two spaces at the end of a line is Markdown's `<br/>`