# Warning that code is not properly formatted as code when editing to add an image

Tags: bug, edits, error-message

I added some image in [my previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50218599). I didn't add extra code while editing. However:

> Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

[image: Screenshot of the warning message quoted above.]

Is it a bug? Or, why does this occur? For reference, I am attempting to edit my question to become:

```
    root@VimLaTeX:/var/www/html/HandicraftStore/Web# du -h
    76K ./font-awesome-4.7.0/css
    128K    ./font-awesome-4.7.0/scss
    128K    ./font-awesome-4.7.0/less
    1.1M    ./font-awesome-4.7.0/fonts
    1.4M    ./font-awesome-4.7.0
    28G .

    root@VimLaTeX:/var/www/html/HandicraftStore/Web# ls
    addToCart.php          checkout.php          jquery-3.3.1.js      productDetails.css  signupSuccessful.html
    auctionDetails.php     cow.jpeg              jquery-3.3.1.min.js  productDetails.php  style.css
    auction.php            database.php          long_poller.html     README.md           takeBid.php
    bootstrap.min.css      delete.html           msgsrv.php           removeToCart.php    test1.html
    bootstrap.min.js       delete.php            navbar.html          search.php          test.php
    carousel.html          font-awesome-4.7.0    newnavbar.php        signinnavbar.html   typeChange.php
    carousel.php           font-awesome.min.css  page1.php            signIn.php          updateAuctionDetails.php
    cart_modal_porton.php  footer.html           page2.php            signOut.php
    cart.php               insertLike.php        popper.min.js        signUp.php

There only one directory `font-awesome-4.7.0` under `Web` rest are files with KB sized. I don't understand why the `Web` directory grab `28GB`. There `HandicraftStore` contains a `.git` folder.


**Edit 1**


[![image 1][1]][1]  
[![image 2][2]][2]  
[![image 3][3]][3]  
[![image 4][4]][4]  
[![image 5][5]][5]  
[![image 6][6]][6]  


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDOCO.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZTD3.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGmLG.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcoR1.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBH3a.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSMBt.png
```

---

[Just a student](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/962603/just-a-student) successfully edited my question. But, my question is why it results in an error while I try to edit. Is this error related to reputation? If it is related to reputation, then the error message should be something about reputation like "you have not enough reputation".

Comment: FWIW, sidenote: Don't do "\*\*Edit 1\*\*". Write *one coherent question*. Don't write a developing story in multiple parts. If you need to add additional information, just insert or rewrite it where it best fits without noting where it has been added. That is visible from the revision history when necessary.

Comment: @deceze it takes less time to view the updated question who are giving time in the question at this time.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the warning. What exactly did you (try to) add to your question?

Comment: Only a vanishingly small number of people are following your question's development in real time. A vastly larger number of people will read it later on in the hopes of finding a solution to their own problem!

Comment: @Justastudent did you try to edit the question? image links 
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDOCO.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZTD3.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGmLG.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcoR1.png
  [5]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBH3a.png
  [6]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSMBt.png

Comment: @deceze Our question is not related to this whether put **Edit 1** or not. You can try to answer my question.

Comment: deceze is giving you good advice, I strongly encourage you to take it, @user9719859. Also, we are all volunteers here, it is not your place to demand deceze tries to answer your question. Let's keep it friendly :-)

Comment: @Justastudent yes. you are right. I edited my comment. I believe that it is a good advice. Actually I want to focus my question.

Comment: @AndréKool yes you are right.

Comment: Weird thing is that you *do* have a blank line before the images.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to reproduce the issue. In fact, I went ahead and submitted [an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50218599/2). It did not trigger the warning for me. It did not even warn me when I did not have [blank lines separating the images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/314444).

As it stands, this question is [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro). At least for me.

I could imagine that this is related to some reputation-related check (I have [editing privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit)).

Comment: I get the error still. https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KY7zQVDDBb/

Comment: Maybe you are getting different results because you have the 2k+ rep edit privileges?

Comment: I just [made the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50218599/2). I was thinking about that, @André, but cannot imagine what could cause it to be different. Inserting images only requires 10 reputation, so that cannot be it.

Comment: Yes, you could edit. But, why SO results error for me?

Comment: You done something different from me and told the question `status-norepro`

Comment: your answer is not-fitted now. Actual answer of the question https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313967/images-being-interpreted-as-incorrectly-formatted-code

Comment: Except I still didn't get an error even without blank lines, which is the solution proposed in the other question. I'll add that to my answer.