# I have this error message when I try to write a code in Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, editor, error-message

> "Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon."

How to correct this error?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why you came to Super User to ask a question about Stack Overflow; that's aside from the fact it belongs on meta over there, not on the main site. BTW, you can find this info above the area you are typing in when you are posting a question or answer. Additionally, how to fix the error is already stated in your question.

Comment: I do not understand. It won't help. I tried to use CTRL+K but nothing happens. By the way I was pointed to Super user.

Comment: @Tetsujin: Can you give me the link what to do to correct this error massage?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313967/images-being-interpreted-as-incorrectly-formatted-code

Answer (score 4):

*This needs migrating to Meta, idk whether SO, SU or SE.

In the meantime...*

*I'm setting pictures inside quotes to make it easier to see they are pictures rather than actual interface.*

Help is available in the box you type your question or answer in, eg...

> [image]

Each of those icons is a function. Each function has a key command which you can see if you hover your cursor over the icon...

> [image]

To format as code you select all your code block, then either click the code icon or hit  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  
This will indent it by 4 spaces, which will tell Markdown it should be formatted as code.

*For example*

This is unformatted code
to coerceToNumber(x)
    local x
    try
        x as number
    on error
        x
    end try
end coerceToNumber

This is the **exact same text**, formatted  by clicking the code icon

```
to coerceToNumber(x)
    local x    
    try
        x as number
    on error
        x
    end try
end coerceToNumber
```

If you ever need additional help with a function, you can find it at the top right of the text box...

> [image]

Clicking this, then your desired function will drop additional help.

> [image]

If you need even more detail, you can click [advanced help](https://superuser.com/editing-help), to the right, which will take you to a separate page

Comment: Code fences are also suitable.