# Does Stack Overflow strive to meet accessibility standards?

Tags: support, accessibility

Does Stack Overflow have a policy to meet [WCAG](https://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20/) or any other accessibility standards? Or is accessibility taken on ad-hoc?

If there is a standard, which one should we be following? WCAG 2. 0 AA for example? And can we submit [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) reports on meta to  make the site more accessible?

Comment: I'm not sure, there are few reports related to [WCAG](http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=wcag) on MSE.

Comment: SO in 2016 still uses fixed width layout, what accessibility you're talking about?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I do not believe that there is any specific strict standard that is followed by the team, which is not to say they do not strive to meet accessibility standards, just that I haven't seen any documentation cited before in this regard.

For the most part, the design seems to follow the guidelines, and there are perhaps several edge cases to address that one could find digging through the specs.

That said, the community is pretty vocal about anything that majorly violates WCAG and I have seen several posts historically citing accessibility as the reason for wanting something changed.

If you feel that there is a particular aspect of the guideline that is problematic, then simply create a post to discuss the observed discrepancy with an example where it is occurring at Stack Overflow and the community/team can at least be aware of it and have some ideas on what needs to be done, if anything.

Comment: Constant misuse of quote markup to make "banners" is my personal favorite problem (code markup, too). That's user-generated, of course, but that also makes it easier to clean up.

Comment: Thanks! Looking at this again, I think any bugs I report (and even this question itself) should be made on meta stack exchange instead of meta SO. Most of the  issues I'm finding exist on all SE sites.

Comment: @JoshCaswell - Hm, to be honest I am not sure what the rules are for user generated content, and do not see guidance in the guidelines with that regards.

Comment: @Godwin - Either exchange is fine. If you see a problem with accessibility on SO, then it is fine to post it to MSO.

Comment: I have only skimmed the linked guideline myself, but I would hope that user-generated content is implicitly included. It's part of the final page that's served to the reader.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: SE also misuses it, e.g. in the spoiler markup (see [Spoiler syntax should generate <div>, not <blockquote>](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253309/193139)).

Comment: Thanks for that note, @unor, I was unaware of it. I support both your proposal and Shog's solution!

Answer (score -4):

I think larger number of usability concerns come from user-submitted content, which makes up the majority of the content on the site.

We should ALWAYS strive to make the site as accessible as possible. Many users have disabilities (including some high rep users, such as [BalusC](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/157882/balusc), who is deaf). Part of being nice is being welcoming, so the site should be as accommodating as possible.

Unfortunately, most people have little to no concern for accessibility.

This seems to happen all the time with pictures. So many people don't bother to provide an alt text, which, in addition to being inaccessible to the visually impaired, has worsened the effects of link rot when the image was not uploaded to Imgur.

This also impairs all search engines from linking to content, which opens up another stream of issues.

Fortunately, some violations, such as [text as an image](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG20/quickref/#qr-visual-audio-contrast-text-images) are widely discouraged by the community at large. Of course, it never stops people from posting code pics (or at least [code pic links](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)), but these questions tend to be shut down fast enough.

Improving accessibility should be a fundamental part of editing; even if *you* can't see the alt text, a screen reader can.

Comment: This isn't really what I was asking about, I wanted to know if there was an expectation of an accessibility standard so that I could ask SO developers to make improvements. I agree what you're talking about is an issue, but that's on us to help solve by responding to users or suggesting new features from devs to help ensure users comply.

Comment: @Godwin The way I see it, the users of Stack Overflow are a huge part of Stack Overflow. Most of the content on this site was contributed by the users, so it is indeed an important thing to discuss. You did not specify that you meant the company in your question, in any case.