# Google shows number of question bookmarks (formerly, favorites) in SO search result

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined

A few months ago, I had asked [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334116/2828434) question on SO meta. I think, SO team or Google team has worked on their code and has resolved the issue as I have not got that issue again. But today, I got this image as a search result: [image: this]

I wondered what that number 4 was, and on opening [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18235169/2828434) question, I came to know that it is not the vote count but the number of times the question has been bookmarked! I know this is not at all a big issue, and may not even affect at large. But as it looked weird, I notified it here on meta.

Comment: I don't think there's much that Stack Overflow can do about this (short of removing the star altogether, or putting it somewhere else)

Comment: They have worked on their code for sure but any change in behavior is an coincidence as that bug report you link to is [meta-tag:status-declined]

Comment: lol, I just saw that *that* bug has "Status-Declined" tag :P

Comment: This is not something Stack Overflow can fix. Google [has the right information](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/?hl=EN#url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18235169%2Funderstanding-angularjs-ng-src), but is displaying the wrong pieces.

Comment: The link for Google's schema recognition reporting tool has changed since 2017, here's the current [link for those same results](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results?url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F18235169%2Funderstanding-angularjs-ng-src&user_agent=1).