# Why do Stack Overflow questions appear weird on Google?

Tags: bug, google

I am seeing this weird number thing in Google search results when they show links to Stack Overflow. Why do the results include a list of other questions that only have a number (or in one case the text "1 Answer") in their title?

[image]

I tried another web browser but still got the same result:

[image]

Search URL : https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket%20connection%20to%20ws://%20failed

another examples;
[image: another]

Comment: Link (in case someone likes to test): https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket%20connection%20to%20ws://%20failed

Comment: Looks like it shows the vote count rather than any more meaningful title. (i.e. clicking through on the 5 takes you to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61571898/rxjs-websocket-websocket-connection-to-ws-localhost3000-failed-connecti which is currently scored 5)

Comment: I think it would be better to ask this on meta.google.com.

Comment: @yivi - Why? Presumably Stackoverflow care about how they are presented in Google results and would like to fix it

Comment: no @Ivar the answer titles converted to numbers in my question. But that answer title is looking correct.

Comment: It seems to be related to the `://` in questions' title. I tried to find more about it but it's hard to search for those characters.

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. It's a different question (not about the number, the tittle is completly empty); and the [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/342226/google-shows-number-of-favorites-in-so-search-result#comment436974_342226) "This is not something Stack Overflow can fix" doesn't apply here. Probably escaping those characters would solve the issue.

Comment: @RafaelTavares ehhh, you are right. Voted to reopen

Comment: I was able to reproduce in Firefox but not in Chrome or Edge. It would be useful for the question to include which specific browsers you tested in.

Comment: It's happening with GitHub hits as well, shows "1 participant" as title when I found an old issue.

Comment: Probably to do with the changing of the markup for question pages tripping Google up for a while

Comment: @TylerH wouldn't that mean that the update botched something in how the metadata is marked up on SE's side? I thought it is defined in a pretty standard manner...

Comment: @OlegValter it's up to Google to use metadata. AFAIK, while google has tools to make sure that data is correctly tagged (microdata, json-ld, etc.) they may decide which of the two has preference for presentation.

Comment: I came across this too. A search for the question title "`Scraping: SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED error for http://en.wikipedia.org`" ([url](https://www.google.com/search?q=Scraping%3A+SSL%3A+CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED+error+for+http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org)) results in this ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkWs1.png)).

Comment: Still happening with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44652434/type-object-is-defined-in-an-assembly-that-is-not-referenced-net-standard-2-0 when I searched for "the type 'object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced".

Comment: This is still happening. Searching for ["spawnSync docker ENOBUFS"](https://www.google.com/search?q=spawnSync+docker+ENOBUFS) resulted in [this](https://i.ibb.co/5MWdWtx/zero.png)

Answer (score -10):

It seems like the problem has been solving slowly, So it seems like Google is flushing cache and recrawl.

[image]

Comment: yeah Google fixed this [completely](https://cln.sh/zggwAx).

Comment: There is no rule that you cannot answer questions unless the problem is completely resolved.  However, as the problem appears to be mostly unsolved, stating that it **is** solved seems incorrect.  This may lead to downvotes on your answer.

Comment: It's not fixed. You searched for other questions... If you see the [link that OP posted](https://www.google.com/search?q=websocket%20connection%20to%20ws://%20failed), the only question title that is fixed is because someone edited it removing the `ws://...`