# Fix the Apple 144/72 insanity

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Problem: obviously and evidently, **many images on the site are 2x as large as they should be** due to the 144/72 dpi duality problem.

---

Long story short, when you take a screen shot on a Mac, it records it at 144 rather than 72 abstract dpi.

HERE IS AN EXAMPLE:

[example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958435)

NOTE THAT IT IS, OBVIOUSLY, DOUBLY-OVERSIZED

[image]

(When I see the problem on a new SO question and have time, **I quickly edit the image down to the correct size, but I can't do 'em all**.)

Solutions could include:

1. some part of the pipeline **understands** that that 144 dpi images should be correctly cut in half for www presentation
2. when dragging in an image, at least some sort of *warning* like "Alert to Mac users, do not upload enormous images"
3. when adding an image.  there's a **button** like "Image far too large? Click here to 50%"
4. i think some folks edit typos, etc with **robots**?  maybe someone could just sweep through the site, identify 144 dpi images and edit them?  IDK
5. more people can jump on the job of manually shrinking the images :/
6. when dragging in an image.  ***the system notices if the image is ridiculously large*** and takes appropriate action (at the very least, just alerting the user to how large it is)

Here's a simple solution:

7. Plain limit the width/height of images uploaded, to some reasonable figure.

Solutions?

---

{Just for anyone who doesn't use a Mac and is curious, the only reasonable workaround to this is you drag something to an external monitor before taking a screenshot; (perhaps even more whackily) it then makes a correct resolution screenshot for internet use.}

Comment: Wait.  Wait, wait, wait.  [What was wrong with the original image provided by the OP?](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59108033/5)  For context, that's been a thing with Android devices too for quite some time IIRC...

Comment: Are they, though?  I'm not really convinced that this is "too" large; I could see an argument for it being "large", but "too" large...?

Comment: I agree, for what it contains it is too large and it is even downsized by SO. Removing the `max-width` CSS property shows the image in the original size.

Comment: I fail to see how your [newly uploaded image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHoOH.png) demonstrates the point that [the OP's image wasn't in the same fix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbWnJ.png).  I suppose the argument you're making is that there's a lot of unnecessary detail in the image - which you've cropped out - but I don't see much of a difference here.  The images are roughly the same proportion, and there's not been any downscaling done on the edited image.  So, I'm lost.

Comment: hi @Tom - that sounds hugely valuable.  Are you saying that "removing the tag" you mention will in fact make it display *respecting the 144 dpi idea* ?  Sorry, I'm not a Web Bloke

Comment: Oh, so it wasn't you that did the crop.  My mistake; I think I read the edit history a bit too fast.  The big thing I'm calling to attention is that the original image was cropped to remove what would be noise from it, but the scale ratio is still the same.  You're suggesting then that the fix needs to be how that image is displayed on the page which is independent of how the image itself is presented on Imgur.  How am I doing so far?

Comment: Would it then make *more* sense for a reasonable edit to an image like that to take the opportunity to downscale it as well?  I could see a wide change to how *all* images are displayed for those of us who don't have/use Macs or i-devices having a knock-on effect.

Comment: No, what I mean is that the picture has such a large dimension, that SO automatically reduces the max width to match site layout. That prevents the image from overlapping into the right sidebar. That doesn't change the actual image. I just meant to say that this image is even bigger than we currently see it.

Comment: hi @Makoto , again, let me explain .. ***indeed I do that all the time!!!***  Heh!  LIke, I'll sit there going through SO, grabbing the image and changing it from 144 to 72 dpi.  Please notice my point 5.

Comment: @Tom - ah, gotchya now bummer.  Say, you seem to know what the hell you're talking about!  In the WWW pipeline, is there a concept of "indicating this is a 144 image" perhaps ?????????

Comment: I mean, I suppose I'm just not seeing the *problem*.  If the problem is that the image is too large, could we take a breath and ask why there's an image here in the first place?  If it's the case that an image is relevant, could we take a breath and say that a reasonable editor should be prepared to downscale it as necessary so that it's not ginormous?  I see that you have an obvious concern about insanity, and it could be the case that *I'm* insane, but I'm just not seeing a *problem* right now...

Comment: hi @Makoto , yes, would you notice my suggestions (2) and (3).  they would VASTLY improve this horrible problem.  BTW, hint, I have removed the now-irrelevant comments from this chain, to reduce clutter. I've removed any comments that refer to a link no longer there.

Comment: Yes @Fattie I've taken a look at your second example and for the life of me I don't know why an image would be more valuable here as opposed to the actual text that they wanted to showcase.  That's why I'm trying to "take a breath" and ask that question.  Is the problem that images are being used inappropriately *manifest* through the symptom that images are too large (for a given quantity of "too large")?

Comment: Your notion that "sometimes images are not needed" seems unrelated.  (1) often they are needed (2) there they are, evidently, in existence.

Comment: If anyone reading is an "anti-image person", then surely .... surely .... as an "anti-image person" you would be doubly offended by the ridiculous reality that about 50% of images on the site (as in the EXAMPLE) are twice as big as they should be.

Comment: **"is there a concept of "indicating this is a 144 image" perhaps"** I'm not that knowledgable in this area, but as far as I know there isn't. There might be a metadata property telling you the DPI/PPI, but if there isn't, then you're out of luck. This is a good Q&A explaining this: [Check dpi of png file](//graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/107888)

Comment: @Tom thanks for that info, what a hassle.  its hard to believe there isn't some simple tech fix for this these days.

Comment: I don’t know if you’re editing the images or just the posts, but hopefully the latter, [as it is all that’s needed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/253405/215552)...

Answer (score 6):

First and foremost, nothing in your question points to anything that could be called "a problem" from my point of view.

Are you really wondering about people with limited internet traffic? There are numerous other fields we could make a fight for them, starting with ads, but honestly, it's been 10 years this fight ended.

I really wonder what's the matter you  have with these "twice as big *on some devices* images"... They get resized to fit the limit of the post size anyway, so if you tell me it breaks the page, that's just a lie.

---

Remember that images on StackOverflow have a really limited scope of acceptability; among which is screenshots of a visual issue. **You changing these screenshots is not different than someone changing the code from an MCVE**. Please stop doing it right now.

For us active in mainly-visual-resulting-code tags like [css] or [canvas], it's not uncommon to get questions where such a screenshot is the first step in diagnosing the issue at hand:
They are using an high-res monitor,

- [ their antialiasing issue is caused by the css shrinking
- [ their performance issue is caused by the fact they got twice pixels to fill
- [ ...

Not only this, but by resizing an image, you are actually removing information which could be useful for answerers.

---

And remember, we don't really like images in here, if you feel an image is disturbing the post, then please consider spending the time you would have spent resizing it to actually convert it to text if applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Right, so here's what I'm thinking.

- **If there is a place where an image is too large, consider if the image belongs there at all.**  If a piece of information is better captured **in text** as opposed to in an image, then opt for using the text.

  I edited the post [you referenced as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/58958435/3), because quite frankly, the image adds *negative* value to that question.  It's well-referenced, and someone who's not in a position to click through to another link may appreciate the quick snippet of code as opposed to downloading some MBs of image.
- **If images are too large *and* they need to be in the question, editors should be prepared to downsize them where and when appropriate.**  This gets us around the issue of an image that needs to be there, but is indeed too large, but is largely community-oriented.

I can't really think of a cleaner way to handle this - [we tend to avoid images in questions where possible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358772/1079354). In light of that, any problem arising from images then smells more like a *symptom*.

Comment: Are you saying of my list of 6 suggestions, you support #5 ?

Comment: What I'm suggesting is that #5 is the only option.

Comment: I appreciate your time and it's interesting to get the view of other users.  (BTW may I suggest you delete your four original comments up top, as they refer to something that is gone and will confuse new readers.)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to detect an image’s dimensions when it is being uploaded: [Is it possible to check dimensions of image before uploading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13572129/is-it-possible-to-check-dimensions-of-image-before-uploading)

So option 2/6 where the site warns them of the image size seems doable.

I don’t think we should automatically resize images because we’re going to end up putting something that’s too hard to see in some posts.