# When editing a question to cleanup grammar and formatting issues, should links to images of text be left as links?

Tags: discussion, edits, images

**Note**: The following does not in any way suggest that anyone should attempt to [transcribe code from an image into text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040/should-we-edit-a-question-to-transcribe-code-from-an-image-to-text).

---

I routinely clean up questions by fixing titles, tags, question grammar, and code formatting. I also routinely add a `!` before an image link to make the image visible when viewing the question. This is typically needed when editing a question from a newer user.

But many times these images are pictures of text (code, error messages, JSON, etc.). And of course the OP should have copied and pasted the actual text instead of posting a picture of the text.

When I come across such images while cleaning up the rest of the post, I have been fixing everything I can except I leave such images as links. I then post a comment explaining that pictures of text should be replaced with the actual text.

My question is whether it is best to leave links to images of text as links or should I add the `!` before the link so the image is seen inline? I feel that making such images visible is kind of rewarding the OP for bad behavior (posting image of text instead of actual text). I'll post the comment either way so they understand the need to replace the image. But does it help or hurt to leave such images as links versus making such images visible inline?

Comment: I would not edit such posts at all. In a lot of cases you will waste your time because the question will be closed and deleted soon. As long as an edit by the author is required, polishing other stuff is not really necessary.

Comment: @BDL Just before making this post I editing a question that had proper code as text. It just need a little cleanup. But it also referenced some JSON the OP wanted to parse but for some reason they posted a picture of the JSON instead of copying and pasting the JSON. It was a perfectly good question except for that one picture. The question deserves no down votes nor deletion. It just needs one picture replaced with text.

Comment: Downvote and close vote are probably not deserved. But probably a close vote. Given that only a low number of closed posts ever gets fixed by the author, the question will be deleted after some time.  I don't say that it's not allowed to edit such posts, you are absolutely free to do that. It's just that a lot of these edits are a lost effort.

Comment: @BDL That's a whole other issue. In many cases the OP does replace the picture with the actual text after seeing my comment. But if the question is quickly deleted and downvoted then the OP just gives up. It's bad for everyone. I usually give the OP a day or two to fix their post before I go back and give it a close vote if needed.

Comment: I agree with your reasoning. I would leave the images as links.

Comment: This is about making images inline. Transcribing images to text is covered by *[Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040)* (the answer is no).

Comment: @PeterMortensen In case there is any confusion, I am definitely not, in any way, suggesting that an editor should transcribe any images. Quite the opposite actually. My whole point is whether the images should be left only as links because the OP needs to replace them with the actual text.

Comment: Leave them as links, the images don't belong.

Comment: [Would you accept an edit where link images of code are replaced by inline images?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358771/3404097) ("No.")

Comment: @philipxy Good find. That didn't come up when I searched before posting. That reinforces my process of leaving the image as a link.

Comment: I googled the end of your title--'should links to images of text be left as links?' (15 yrs now, was that question going to be new?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040/should-we-edit-a-question-to-transcribe-code-from-an-image-to-text)

Comment: @ArunVinoth-PrecogTech-MVP No. My question has absolutely nothing to do with attempting to transcribe code from an image.

Comment: Why are there 3 close votes using the completely unrelated "Should we edit a question to transcribe code from an image to text?" post? I've replied to two specific comments regarding that post as well as updating the start of my question with a clear note that it isn't relevant.

Comment: My comment was pointing out this question was ***not*** about transcribing images. Apparently it wasn't clear enough. I should have written something like "... This is ***different*** from transcribing images to text, which is covered by ..." to make it abundantly clear they are two different things.

Comment: The confusion may have come from the first answer (now deleted).

Comment: I used the wrong close target but you can't change a close vote, only undo it & lose it.

Comment: I'm not sure why the edit to this post was necessary. Nothing in the question body carries such an implication that I can see. Maybe the title could be a bit clearer?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I made the edit after an answer (now deleted), several comments, and now 4 close votes all brought up the idea of transcribing image text. The real annoying thing is that 2 of the close votes have come after I made the edit.

Comment: @ArunVinoth-PrecogTech-MVP The question is only tangentially related at best. I have [left the question open in review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/review/close/32041).

Answer (score 7):

This takes some justification and caveats, but: yes, I typically inline such images, and encourage others to do so as well.

Caveats first:

- Do not inline the image if the question is a duplicate. It is highly unlikely that edits will make it not a duplicate without radically changing the question. Duplicates need to work as signposts, and fixing them to be answerable is not a priority since they will not receive separate answers. If the question as written could not stand by itself without the image, then it will most likely not function as a good signpost, and should be deleted later.
- [Please do not attempt to transcribe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/415040) the image.
- **Please also vote or flag the question for closure** as appropriate. It is not a conflict of interest; on the contrary, you are *cooperating* with OP to fix the post with the grammar/formatting fixes.
- Please also consider every other action available to you to improve the post:

  - If something is unclear and you can't figure it out, leave that alone in editing and instead give specific, detailed feedback as to *what* needs to be clarified. Similarly if information is missing: describe what is missing, as it may not be obvious to the OP.
  - Try as much as possible to remove noise and redundancy and improve the overall flow of the post. (This is typically easier with subject matter expertise.)
  - For older questions, check the answers and see if they are dependent on exact code in the image. If not, it would generally be better to construct an artificial example of the problem. Answers should be edited *anyway* such that they avoid a discussion-forum tone and address the general form of the problem, rather than OP's exact circumstance.

    If it's a relatively "important" question (high scores on questions and answers, high view count, high inbound links, etc.) and both the question and answers need work (especially if answers were written corresponding to code in the image), consider soliciting help on Meta or in the chat rooms.

And some justification:

- Showing the image inline makes the problem more obvious to other curators, and allows them to give the OP more specific feedback - by linking them to [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551). This is especially important in cases where OP messed up the syntax badly enough that there isn't even an image link - it's easy for others to overlook that there was any attempt to show code (or an error, etc.) at all.
- While such a post does not meet standards, the post is still *temporarily better off* with the image inlined. This at least allows others to evaluate properly whether the question *can be salvaged*.
- I am [generally a proponent of moving posts in the right direction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420349/_/420357#420357). Visible code is better than not-visible code, even if it's in an unsuitable form.

Comment: No images of text -> images of text is the WRONG direction.

Comment: @philipxy On the other hand, closing unsalvageable posts and doing what you can to fix salvageable ones seems like exactly the right direction.

Comment: @tripleee Don't get your point. My point is "fix salvageable ones" doesn't include introducing images of text.