# How should I flag an image-only question?

Tags: discussion, questions, images

While reviewing my triage queue I'm getting lots of questions where code is posted as an image and not as text. My question is: how do I flag those questions? To me the most appropriate way is flagging as "unclear what you asking". But I am not sure if it is the correct way.

Comment: *"unclear what you asking"* - sounds reasonable to me for an *"image-only question"*. For a question with the code as image though I generally prefer *"Off-topic - Questions seeking debugging help..."*

Comment: I'd pick either "Unclear what you are asking" or the "Incomplete MCVE" option

Comment: see also: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/839601)

Comment: @gnat the second link you typed seems more specific and more appropriate to the case.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This off-topic close reason seems suitable:

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers.

Since the code and/or the error are in an image, they are not "in the question itself". I sometimes add a comment with a short explanation and a link to this answer: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 ("You should not post code as an image because...")

Comment: I wonder (with the new triage code): Shouldn't there be a reason for "author edit" to tell something like "presentation of input does not meet guidelines (e.g.: code presented as image)? If not, which is the correct choice?

Comment: @U.Windl Good question! I think it merits being posted as a question by itself.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/403654/6607497