# Flagging of badly asked questions in the triage queue

Tags: discussion, triage

While reviewing questions in the [triage queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review), I sometimes see questions that are downvoted and not answered because the question is badly asked. For example, a question with not much text and lots of code images.

In that case, I would really want to flag the question and leave a comment to the author of the question. But I don't know what response is the most appropriate. In that case, I leave the queue, go to the question and add a comment and skip the question.

I have a feeling there must be a better way to handle this type of questions.

Any advice?

Comment: The point of the triage queue is to triage the question to have it sent to the correct queue. If the question has images of code, then select "Needs Author Edit" and Submit that. The question will likely go in the Close Votes queue for *proper* review, where people can advise the problem to the OP and vote to close it.

Comment: if I select 'needs author edit', I get 5 options. Of that options I choose  does not meet the guidelines. But then I get a list where I cannot find an appropriate choice. Is it better to pick an unsuitable one, then to leave a comment the way I do?

Comment: "Needs debugging details" would be appropriate. Images of code are not code and effectively can be seen as "non-existent".

Comment: Re *"lots of code images"*: A canonical is *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)*. Though it doesn't say anything about review queues. Maybe it should. Or make a reference to a place that does.

Comment: Related: *[How should I flag an image-only question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376930/how-should-i-flag-an-image-only-question)* (also triage queue)

Comment: Leaving a comment with specific advice, as you describe, is indeed helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the question is 'badly asked' because it has unformatted code, capitalized 'i's, grammatical errors, etc. then you should click *Needs community edit*.

On the other hand, if a question is missing critical information and cannot be answered as is or is off-topic, you should *Needs author edit* if you think the question can be salvaged through the author editing (Needs debugging details) or *Flag* if the question is a duplicate, blatantly off-topic, etc. and is unlikely to be salvageable by the author.

This way, the question can go to the appropriate queue (such as the Close Votes queue for questions that the consensus is *Needs author edit* or *Flag*) or go be published to the homepage.