# How to handle questions of which the OP doesn't use any kind of translator and cannot speak English

Tags: discussion, questions, comments, specific-question

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54551848/7571526) yesterday and wanted the OP to put some more information to his question as his question appears to be not a good question.

---

#### Comment history under the question

Me:

> Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: What worked fine bevor the error? / What have you done before the error? and please do not use images for showing code or errors! For Help take a look at "How to ask"

OP:

> Well this is photo uploaded. This is no code issue. Its a "netbeans" issue while launching it.

Me:

> Then tell us if there was a update or anything else. Otherwise this will be a quiz show... and this question is deleted. Please put more effort in a question if you want a serious answer.

OP:

> Now that the image is rendered in the post, u can help me

Me:

> Please use translate.google.com or anything similar if you can not understand someone correctly or you are not sure while writing...

OP:

> do u want me to translate above Warning instead of searching in google.com?

---

I don't think the OP is understanding anything of what I have written and if I'm writing more comments trying to explain my intentions then there would be a huge amount of unnecessary (and unrelated) comments.

How should I handle such a case as the question doesn't seem to be deleted or made on hold?

Comment: If the question is not clear enough, flag to close as unclear. Maybe downvote. Move on.

Comment: @yivi I did both of it already, but I would like to help. (Which seems to be useless)

Comment: There are limits to the help we can give. If there is serious understanding problem, there is only so much one can do. You tried, it didn't work. My advise: move on to greener pastures. SO is not meant to be a personal help desk.

Comment: @Hille *"but I would like to help"* - of course you do, but you can't teach a person English; a hard prerequisite if you want to use the English Stack Overflow site. This person needs to help themselves before you can help them.

Comment: Reopening this - on the surface the dupe is correct but this is a specific enough case that it warrants individual explanation.

Comment: Re-closing this. The OP there has problems understanding someone that's trying to help him edit his question into shape... I think the dupe target covers that.

Comment: @Cerbrus:  This reads like a rather narrow interpretation of this scenario.  The comments are *noise* at best, since the question itself was actually clear and in reality, the only improvement made by *this* OP was adding the image into the question (which, ironically, gave people *more* ammunition to disapprove of the question).  This wasn't a question about edits.  This wasn't really a question about a lack of understanding.  This was about comments which **do not apply in this context.**  I think I'd know - I'm the one who answered that dupe you're linking to.

Answer (score 6):

I would say, down-vote and move on,

If you have enough reputation, also close.

You don't need to keep dragging on to the question, move on instead.

Answer (score -4):

I didn't see anything particularly *wrong* with either the question, or the English used to describe the problem.  It feels like you made some assumptions about the OP, and despite their best efforts to explain and illustrate the problem to you, the comments you left read like they're kiting the actual question.

This revision - where you actually add the image in to describe the issue - still reads like a clear and concise question, which doesn't seem to be worthy of downvotes or close votes for clarity...

[image]

...and *sure*, you could make the argument that English is not the OP's first language, but then again...not seeing a problem with the question as phrased.

At *worst*, this is a dupe - some searches on Google hint at things which *might* fix the problem.

At *best*, this could be answered by someone who has used Netbeans 10 on Ubuntu 18.10, and has encountered it.

If some information is ***missing***, then the comment chain should have been used to request *that* instead of making comments about the OP's use of a translator.

Comment: To be clear, that is a terrible, unacceptable question because it does not include the text of the error message.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I half-disagree.  Sure, having text would be nice, but IDE errors can be explained through images.  Sometimes, IDE errors can *only* be explained through images.  Now, if the image is the *only* gripe, would an edit be sufficient to remove any qualms about it?

Comment: I would close that question without a second thought. Screenshots of error messages are not acceptable. Images are not searchable. I don't really know what *else* might be a gripe about this question. There isn't enough question to even measure.

Comment: @CodyGray:  I suppose, again, if the error were actually in text, I don't think there'd be much of a problem, but I do fundamentally reject the "close without a second thought" mentality on this since, unlike *code*, which does no one any favors if it's in an image, an edit on this *could've* saved it.  Now it's been deleted by the system so I'm not really interested in raising this from the bottom of the ocean.  I'm more calling out the Meta OP's behavior here in believing that the issue was an *online translator*.

Comment: I'm fascinated by the distinction you are able to make between images of code (which is text) and images of error messages (which are also text). How do [the problems of one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors) not translate one-to-one to the other?

Comment: I'm more making a distinction between images of code and images of tools.  I haven't used Netbeans in almost seven years, but I don't recall those error messages being exactly *copyable*.  I use IntelliJ these days and *some* messages you get in certain awkward situations, you legitimately *cannot* copy to satisfy the Stack Overflow requirement.  I don't disagree that images of errors aren't *ideal*.  I **do not** see them in the same light as images of code; unlike code, you can't always run your IDE to produce the same error in the same way.

Comment: @CodyGray Isn't it a standard to usually ask for OP to edit their question when something is wrong instead of outright close it? I'm just asking to know, 'cause I used to believe that's how it's done (mostly on the other SE websites actually).

Comment: My first comment was a request for more information - as you can see in the question - and the question **is not** about how good my **edit requests** are or what the **question is missing**... It's about handling low effort and badly translated questions. So this is getting off the track really fast.

Comment: @Clockwork No, not at all. Closing should be done *first*, and *then* the question can be edited and re-opened. That's how it's done everywhere. You do not, and should not, "wait" because (A) you do not know how long you will be waiting, and (B) a bunch of useless answers can flood in while you're waiting. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260263/how-long-should-we-wait-for-a-poster-to-clarify-a-question-before-closing and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98022/how-soon-should-i-vote-to-close

Comment: @Makoto about the image problem: the op want the help of some strangers but won't even invest enough effort to copy the text from an image to text? I think there's something wrong if we can't expect a little bit of work bevor getting answers.

Comment: @Hille:  This is why I think you're kiting the actual question.  Sure, you have a *point*, but in context to what we're looking at here, the error code being an image is something which is ***trivially*** edited away.  I will point out that your edit *didn't* do that.  I give these kinds of questions more benefit of the doubt than a little since, well, if that's really the only barrier to make a question about a person's IDE problem Acceptable™, then that's not too bad.

Comment: @Hille:  You may think that I'm somehow missing the point of your question, but I'm challenging the very premise of the question. I saw nothing in the question to suggest that the OP was using a translation service or was not communicating effectively.  I'm calling you out; there was definitely some bias there which was unnecessary and unfruitful.