# How often should I include screenshots of command outputs?

Tags: discussion, images, rules, image-upload

I recently created an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55198454/1426539) to explain how to solve a problem with Python's `http.server`.

The answer required basic knowledge of commands like `ps`, `grep`, `kill` & `killall`.

Since I wasn't sure how much the OP knew, I included a screenshot of the output and went on to explain what it all meant.

Should I have included the screenshot and are there rules for when they should be included?

Comment: You can use screenshots if they are useful for your answer. If the output is text, just pasting it the answer is more appropriate.

Comment: Is there something in particular that prompted you to ask this Meta question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: (although the suggested duplicate target is about questions, I think it applies on answers as well, for the most part)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: In this example, a good description of what the user will see "You'll get a list of PIDs like this:" would make the answer work without  the image.  Honestly I think the question is off-topic as 'not useful to others' as it was fundamentally a typo...

Comment: Related: [Why are images of text, code and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052/why-are-images-of-text-code-and-mathematical-expressions-discouraged/320060#320060)

Comment: Whenever the expected output of the command is an image...

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you are adding output of a command or something that can be pasted into the answer as text you should be doing that instead of including a picture of the text. Including text in a post is better than a screen shot for several reasons.

- Some users are on networks that block imgur rendering the image useless to them
- If the user is using a screen reader they will not be able to get anything from the picture
- If they do not speak the language fluently they may need to run it through a translator and that can't be easily done with an image.
- If you want anything to be done with the output that you posted it will be a lot harder if it is an image.
- Users can search for terms that are in the output which can help find what they are looking for
- The text will scale with the resolution of the screen being used which can be very helpful on mobile devices with smaller screen.
- It will use less bandwith if it is just loading text versus an image

In truth avoiding posting images when you can post it as text instead will make it more user friendly for all users.

Comment: One more reason that's often relevant (though not in this particular case): users searching for error messages and the like will only find them if they're posted as text.

Comment: Also images of text can be really hard to read on a small screen (i.e. phone), as they usually requite horizontal scrolling to read.

Comment: @dfeuer Excellent point, I have added it (was something I forgot to include)

Comment: @CrisLuengo Good point that is something I didn't consider

Answer (score 5):

Without disagreeing with anything that @JoeW has written, there are occasions where including an image **in addition to** the raw text could be useful.  It's limited to things like discussing syntax highlighting, etc that can't easily be represented as text.

(Theoretically you could use a snippet and use html/css to create a text block with arbitrary colors to match whatever tool you're discussing uses, but that's a bit grotesque.)

Comment: There are *very* few questions on the site which would be justified in talking about syntax highlighting.  You're mostly looking at scripts which build out ANSI colored output, but the people who want to do that probably have an idea of what they're looking for.

Comment: @Makoto I totally agree it's an edge case.

Comment: @Makoto Or questions which discuss configuration of syntax highlighting in IDEs…

Comment: @duskwuff - that's a gray area...

Comment: @Makoto How so? "Software tools commonly used by programmers" -- like IDEs -- [are explicitly in scope](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: I would conjecture that asking us how to set up specific syntax highlighting lands *just* outside the scope of what we want to discuss.  We can get you up and running with having Java and Python running in your IDE side-by-side.  I'm *less* interested in helping you configure the color of your IDE to match the Rocky Mountains.

Comment: I would like to note that syntax highlighting doesn't really matter much on stack overflow as it doesn't make the text anymore readable in the long run and the color scheme that is used on the website might not even match the editor that the person getting the information uses (if they even use on that supports it)