# Do answers that post only, but obvious, code screenshots deserve to be deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

I recently stumbled upon this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64841298/1974224.

[image]

The (self) answer makes it pretty clear what the problem was. I'd even argue that the actual source code is not needed, as the answerer made it pretty clear where the problem was - the `Style` element was misplaced, and the actual source code would not help much since it's less likely that someone will need the exact same contents for the misplaced element.

Yes, the answer could've been better, yes the answerer could've add code snippets, but should it have been deleted? I'd say no. Closing the question as a typo? Maybe yes. But the answer adds value.

Comment: If the question deserves to be closed as a typo, there is no reason in spending any time and energy saving it from deletion. The whole thing was going to go eventually in any case.

Comment: And an answer with code posted as a image should be deleted as not an answer. Without the images there was simply not answer. Yes, the whole code was not actually needed, but an actual answer ("`<Style>` belongs inside `<ResourceDictionary>`, not directly inside `<Application.Resource>`") was the way to go. Actual code showing the problem wouldn't go amiss.

Comment: Images of code are bad for a number of reasons. If it's an image of something that can be reproduced as plain text, it should at least be accompanied by text, if not replaced by text. Images can't be copy-pasted, or read by screen readers or people who for a number of reasons (i.e. something blocking the image site, the image site being down, etc.) can't see the image won't be able to understand what "right place" and "wrong place" means

Comment: @yivi yes, text is most of the times better than images, yes the answer could've been in a better shape. Did it deserve to be deleted, though?

Comment: yes, it did. It's useless without the images, which may or may not exist independently of Stack Overflow - that's why images are problematic

Comment: Yes, it was not an answer. So, it had to go. If edited into shape (e.g. made a proper answer), it could be undeleted. Is it worth it, though?

Comment: Related: [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/2821954), [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2821954) (some of the reasons also apply to image-only answer)

Comment: @Zoe ok, so the OP made a mistake and posted images, should we be in such a rush that a mod needs to delete the answer? AFAIK posts deleted my mods can't be that easily undeleted. Why did we need a mod for this answer? Shouldn't the community be enough? This is another thing that I don't understand for this particular case.

Comment: Bhargav frequently gets involved in NAAs. So do a couple other mods. It can't be undeleted by normal users, but it can be mod-flagged for undeletion.

Comment: Effort should not be spent to improve the answer to a question caused by a typo.  Even if the answer contained the corrected code the question should still be closed since it was caused by a typo.

Comment: Also, for good measure, here's what the answer looks like to someone who can't see the images for any reason at all (ironically presented as an image, because I don't feel like posting an answer): https://i.imgur.com/pCLAeQK.png - would you consider an answer like that useful? More specifically, if you're in that situation, does that answer make the solution obvious?

Answer (score 9):

> Yes, the answer could've been better,

Then make it better

> yes the answerer could've add code snippets,

Then add those code snippets

> but should it have been deleted?

If all we have are images with *wrong* and *right* labels and the problem isn't about some visual glitch then that answer didn't add value and is better deleted.

> I'd say no.

We have to disagree then.

> Closing the question as a typo? Maybe yes. But the answer adds value.

What would have added value was recoverability of that answer. That mostly happens with the aid of search engines. As far as I know Google still doesn't OCR all images so the only way it can know that answer is about a misplaced Style element outside of a ResourceDictionary element is by crawling the text of that answer. And those critical words are not in that answer. And I'm pretty sure there is some official documentation that shows/explains what goes in a RecourceDictionary and where a Style element belongs. All kind of context to make that answer useful and have it pop-up in searches.

When I have posted this, my answer probably serves as a better signpost to that answer then the answer itself. Let's agree that we delete non-value from the main site, please?

Comment: Agreed, non-valuable posts are just garbage piling up on SO, and we had plenty of bad stuff accumulating in the last years. What I argue here is the fact that the answer adds value.

Comment: "Google still doesn't OCR all images" - this holds for when asking questions, because 99% of the people that end up on SO from search engines are looking for other people that had the same problems. Answers a little bit different, because you don't usually search for text in the answer, but for text in the question.

Comment: @Cristik depends. If I'm looking for dupes, I'm usually paying more attention to the answers than questions